# To find the no. of ordered n-tuple solutions of an equation

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

In an equation:-
$$a+b+c=n$$ the no. of whole number solutions is ${n+2}\choose{2}$
Similarly for any equation of the form:-
$\sum_{i=1}^{j}a_i=k$ the no. of solutions is ${k+j-1}\choose{j-1}$

But can we formulate some general equation for the no. of whole number solutions of:-
$$\sum_{i=0}^{j}n_i a_i=k$$ where $n_i$ are constant values

Eg:- To find the no. of solutions of $2a+3b+2c+d=20$

Answer (score 0):

A direct formula may not be possible but we can use generating function to find the number of solution for the example problem that you have stated.

That is you will have to find the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the following products of g.f

$(1+x^2+x^4+..)^2(1+x^3+x^6+...)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)$

The number of solutions is $\boxed{192}$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B10%7D+x%5E(2i))%5E2(%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B7%7D+x%5E(3i))(%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B20%7D+x%5Ei)

Comment: could you pls explain how u formed the first polynomial by generating functions??

Comment: There are four variables and think of them as urns. The first and third urns should contain balls of 0, 2, 4, 6 in numbers, the third one should contain balls of 0,3,6.. and the last one is any number from 0,1,2..

Comment: creating generating fucntions as part of discrete mathematics is very interesting I had a pdf but it is in a different computer than the one that i amm using now

Comment: It would help if u could post it

Comment: I will certainly when I get a hand on it.  Good luck\

Comment: One more thing How would u find the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expansion without expanding it actually?

Comment: For problems like this, it may not be practical, you may have to use softwares like wolfram .  Interestingly it is all series of geometric progression and may simplify to shorter expression.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B10%7D+x%5E(2i))%5E2(%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B7%7D+x%5E(3i))(%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B20%7D+x%5Ei).  The answer is 192